# Allegro5 with MS Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, allegro5

I've tried to install allegro for my MS Visual Studio 2012. I was fallowing instructions from allegro wiki. Everything succed with compiling example application, but there is one error that i can't find help about. After running application I'm reciving this error: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYIC9.png). 
It says that application wasn't run properly. Do you have any idea why is it? It's my first meet with allegro so I don't have any clue.

Edit:
First my system was missing msvcr120d.dll so I've downloaded them and put in Windows\System32 and then I've recived this error.

Error message says: "Application wasn't properly launched (0xc000007b). Click OK button to close application."

What MS Visual Studio says: "Unhandled exception at 0x7779E052 (ntdll.dll) in Allegro1.exe: 0xC000007B: Program %hs isn't dedicated to launch in system Windows or contains error."

Comment: Please post the error message as text rather than as a screen shot. It's easier for those of us who don't read Polish (forgive me if I've guessed wrong) to plug the text into Google Translate.

Comment: msvcr120d.dll is debug version of Visual Studio 2103 runtime. It is not supposed to be redistributable. If you don't want any further surprises, I suggest you delete the downloaded library from your System32 folder. Also, you said you are building with VS2012. How comes your app needs that DLL? Could it be that you linked to VS2013 version of Allegro5 libraries instead of VS2012 version?

Comment: Oh, good to know. I've trusted one website that said it's allegro for VS2012 and it might be problem. I'll check it all again if it's correct version and delete this DLL file

Comment: Thank you very much Paul. The problem was version of allegro library. I've downloaded correct one this time from allegro website and everything is working.